# Unity URP, how to disable MSAA in a custom renderpass?

Tags: unity-game-engine, rendering, pipeline, render, urp

I have a custom render pass. I re-render the entire screen overriding a few renderer layers with different materials. This new RT is then blitted through a material that uses this new colour data to perform edge detection, before being blended back over the original BLITSource.

[image: Edge detection result, without MSAA]

With no MSAA the edges are detected cleanly. However, with MSAA the extra samples make it inaccurate.

[image: Edge detection result, with MSAA looking rough]

I want to remove MSAA from my second render pass, but not the original blitSource.

```
public class OutlinesPass : ScriptableRenderPass
    {
        private MySettings settings;
        private FilteringSettings filteringSettings;
        private ProfilingSampler _profilingSampler;
        private List<ShaderTagId> shaderTagsList = new List<ShaderTagId>();
        private RTHandle rtCustomColor;
        private RTHandle rtTempColor;
        public OutlinesPass(MySettings settings, string name)
        {
            this.settings = settings;
            filteringSettings = new FilteringSettings(RenderQueueRange.opaque);

            shaderTagsList.Add(new ShaderTagId("SRPDefaultUnlit"));
            shaderTagsList.Add(new ShaderTagId("UniversalForward"));
            shaderTagsList.Add(new ShaderTagId("UniversalForwardOnly"));

            _profilingSampler = new ProfilingSampler(name);
        }


        private uint GetRendererLayers(List<int> components)
        {
            uint filteredRenderingLayer = uint.MaxValue;
            if (components != null && components.Count > 0)
            {
                filteredRenderingLayer = 0;
                foreach (uint a in components)
                {
                    int b = ((int)1 << (int)a);
                    filteredRenderingLayer |= (uint)b;
                }
            }
            return filteredRenderingLayer;
        }

        public override void OnCameraSetup(CommandBuffer cmd, ref RenderingData renderingData)
        {
            var colorDesc = renderingData.cameraData.cameraTargetDescriptor;

           //renderingData.cameraData.postProcessEnabled = true;
           // renderingData.cameraData.antialiasing = AntialiasingMode.SubpixelMorphologicalAntiAliasing;
           // renderingData.cameraData.antialiasingQuality = AntialiasingQuality.High;

            colorDesc.depthBufferBits = 0;
            colorDesc.colorFormat = RenderTextureFormat.ARGBHalf;
            colorDesc.msaaSamples = 1;

            RenderingUtils.ReAllocateIfNeeded(ref rtTempColor, colorDesc, name: "_TemporaryColorTexture");
            RenderingUtils.ReAllocateIfNeeded(ref rtCustomColor, colorDesc, name: settings.colorTargetDestinationID);

            RTHandle rtCameraDepth = renderingData.cameraData.renderer.cameraDepthTargetHandle;
            ConfigureTarget(rtCustomColor, rtCameraDepth);
            ConfigureClear(ClearFlag.Color, new Vector4(0.0f,0.0f,0.0f,0.0f));


        }

        public override void Execute(ScriptableRenderContext context, ref RenderingData renderingData)
        {
            CommandBuffer cmd = CommandBufferPool.Get();

            using (new ProfilingScope(cmd, _profilingSampler))
            {

                context.ExecuteCommandBuffer(cmd);
                cmd.Clear();

                SortingCriteria sortingCriteria = renderingData.cameraData.defaultOpaqueSortFlags;
                DrawingSettings drawingSettings = CreateDrawingSettings(shaderTagsList, ref renderingData, sortingCriteria);

                filteringSettings.renderingLayerMask = GetRendererLayers(settings.basicOutlineRenderingLayermask);
                if (settings.uniqueColorMaterial != null)
                {
                    drawingSettings.overrideMaterial = settings.uniqueColorMaterial;
                }
                context.DrawRenderers(renderingData.cullResults, ref drawingSettings, ref filteringSettings);

                filteringSettings.renderingLayerMask = GetRendererLayers(settings.complexOutlineRenderingLayermask);
                if (settings.characterInformationMaterial != null)
                {
                    drawingSettings.overrideMaterial = settings.characterInformationMaterial;
                }
                context.DrawRenderers(renderingData.cullResults, ref drawingSettings, ref filteringSettings);

                cmd.SetGlobalTexture(settings.colorTargetDestinationID, rtCustomColor);

                RTHandle camTarget = renderingData.cameraData.renderer.cameraColorTargetHandle;
                if (camTarget != null && rtTempColor != null)
                {
                    Blitter.BlitCameraTexture(cmd, camTarget, rtTempColor, settings.fullScreenMaterial, 0);
                    Blitter.BlitCameraTexture(cmd, rtTempColor, camTarget);
                }
            }
            context.ExecuteCommandBuffer(cmd);
            cmd.Clear();
            CommandBufferPool.Release(cmd);
        }

        public override void OnCameraCleanup(CommandBuffer cmd) { }

        public void Dispose()
        {
            rtCustomColor?.Release();
            rtTempColor?.Release();
        }
    }
```

To this end, I hard code the render pass to have MSAA samples of 1 (disabled). However when I enable MSAA in the render pipeline asset, the render pass only renders black. If I hard code the MSAA samples of my pass to 4 for example, it will render black until the pipeline asset value in the inspector matches 4. This is very confusing. How can I disable MSAA in my render pass, but not game wide. Thankyou. This is URP btw.